Screw through electrical wire. Explosive result
Let me say this again, at the top. When I get it working, I'll rewire it permanently into a box on the other side of the wall.
I replaced the section of 12-2 cable, but the outlets still don't work. What else could be wrong? Could I have damaged more than the wires?
My electrician, who was checking to see if he had created a problem, checked the next item in the line (the bathroom light) and the breaker. Those items looked fine to him.
Here's my repair. Obviously, it's not in a box. I plan to cut hole and install a box on the other side of the wall once I get it working.

I know this may open a can of worms, but can the problem be something other than
• the rewiring
• the breaker or
• a yet unfound GFCI?
I'm in Alaska.
Crip569-Yes, I checked all the gfci's.
Also, the wire nuts are 4 and 4. It's just hard to see them all.
Aloyishus-See above. The electrician and I did all you suggested. He was here on another job and couldn't stay for this.

Did you check/reset GFCI receptacles and/or checked the breaker was turned back on.

A picture of your panel might identify whether you have old (/bad) breakers.

Also, did you open up the next receptacle between the break and the panel?

Vtc, needs additional information.

Please take the [tour]. You posted two answers below that aren't answers. There's an Edit button right up there for you to add new information to your original post.

The wire nut numbers should match at each end.  you have one end with three and one end with four.  This is usually not right(99 to 1).  You want black to black, white to white, bare/green to bare/green, and it looks like red to red.  Anything else will give problems.

What county are you in? If the US there are multiple things wrong with that installation, from unprotected wires too close to the surface to splices not made in a junction box.

That freaking mess will all have to be undone to "put it in a box".
